# Formatting string ticklabels matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of ticklabels that are strings on my x axis, and I want to be able to get -> modify -> set them. Say for example I have a plot that looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(1,6), range(5))
plt.xticks(range(1,6), ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

and I want to change the labels on the x axis to `['(a)','(b)','(c)','(d)','(e)']`

what is the simplest/best way to do this? I've tried things like:

```
labels = ['(%s)' % l for l in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()]
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(labels)
```

but `ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()` returns matplotlib Text objects as opposed to a list of strings and I'm not sure how to go about modifying them. I also tried using `matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter` but could only get a hold of the numeric positions not the labels themselves. Any would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One more layer to unpeel:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(1,6), range(5))
plt.xticks(range(1,6), ['a','b','c','d','e'])

labels = ['(%s)' % l.get_text() for l in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()]
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(labels)
```

your code but with `l.get_text()` in the list comp where there was a `l`.

Comment: Wow I was looking through the Text object methods and completely missed that one... Thanks!